# When a query creates a new column, how do I then refer to this column in a 'Where' clause?

Tags: sql-server

My query creates a new column using a `CASE` expression.

How do I then refer to this column in a subsequent `WHERE` clause?

Am I best to query this column via a `WHEN` expression in the original `CASE` line?

Comment: You would have to put your basic query into a subquery or CTE in order for the outer query code to be able to refer to this newly created "on-the-fly" column by name

Answer (score 1):

You would have to put your basic query into a subquery or CTE in order for the outer query code to be able to refer to this newly created "on-the-fly" column by name.

Based on the [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), you **cannot** directly refer to a newly introduced "on-the-fly" column in your `WHERE` clause (since the `WHERE` clause is processed before the list of columns in your `SELECT`) .

Something like:

```
SELECT (list-of-columns)
FROM
    (SELECT
         (list-of-columns),
         CASE ...... END AS NewColumn
     FROM 
         dbo.YourTable) x
WHERE
    x.NewColumn = .......
```

or with a CTE:

```
USING YourBaseCTE AS 
(
     SELECT
         (list-of-columns),
         CASE ...... END AS NewColumn
     FROM 
         dbo.YourTable
) 
SELECT (list-of-columns)
FROM YourBaseCTE
WHERE NewColumn = .......
```